# Android ViewPager in only left side scroll

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, scroll, android-viewpager

In my case I have one custom view pager. I want it to scroll to the left side only, the right side scroll are disabled. I tried:

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        int Pos = pager.getCurrentItem();

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
            mCurrentPage = pager.getCurrentItem();
            if (position == mCurrentPage) {
                // It's gone to right.
                if (positionOffset > -4) {
                    // setPage(position + 1);
                    pager.setCurrentItem(position + 1);
                }
                // Not yet.
                else {
                    // setPage(position);
                    pager.setCurrentItem(position);
                }
            } else {
                // It's gone to left.
                if (positionOffset < 0.5) {
                    // setPage(position);
                    pager.setCurrentItem(position);
                }
                // Not yet.
                else {
                    // setPage(position + 1);
                    pager.setCurrentItem(position + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // mCurrentPage = position;
            // pager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
    });
```

But it did not work and i also checked

[How to disable ViewPager from swiping in one direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602369/how-to-disable-viewpager-from-swiping-in-one-direction?lq=1)

[How to know ViewPager has scrolled half the screen in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819865/how-to-know-viewpager-has-scrolled-half-the-screen-in-android)

[Viewpage stop swiping in a certain direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224581/viewpage-stop-swiping-in-a-certain-direction)

But I can't make it work.