# Android - Smooth transition of TabLayout indicator color on slide between tabs

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I've seen several apps smoothly changing their indicator color (even icons!) on tab swipe for example Facebook.

This is how I do it in my app :

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
        new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(searchViewPager) {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabSelected(tab);
                tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(indicatorColors[tab.getPosition()]));
            }
        });
```

Where indicatorColors is an array of normal color, and thus it only changes when user completely swipes to a tab or select the tab. I need the transition here.

What can I do to get a smooth color transition from one color to another color on tab swipe?

`TabLayout` is coupled with a `ViewPager`.

Comment: I didn't tried it. But I think this can be achieved by setting a ScrollListener on the TabLayout or the ViewPager.

Comment: Hmm I just reviewed `setOnScrollChangeListener`, yes it can be done through here, but it needs API min 23 and I am using API min 17.. Any other way?

Comment: I think this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14111712/5460053

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
...onCreate(){

...
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {

    setTabColor(tabHost);
}
 });
 setTabColor(tabHost);
```

...
}

```
//Change The Backgournd Color of Tabs

public void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {

    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) {
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(COLOR_CYAN); 
    }

    //unselected

    if(tabhost.getCurrentTab()==0){
           tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(COLOR_RED); //1st tab selected
    } else {
           tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(COLOR_BLUE); //2nd tab selected
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same what I am currently doing.. But this is on tab changed.. And not using `TabLayout`

Comment: Ok. Then please explain what is the issue.

Comment: So I'm using `TabLayout` and wishes to add a smooth transition of color from one tab to another tab, example : `light blue` to `blue` to `dark blue` (imagine gradient color) while sliding from tab `0` to tab `1`, what I have is now `light blue` to `dark blue`.

Comment: Are you using TabLayout with ViewPager?